# How can I set https: at first of my domain name

Tags: wordpress, ssl, dns

I've a wordpress site **www.example.net**. Usually when visitors visit my site, the domain name look like this **example.net** in the browser addressbar. Recently I added an SSL certificate in my website, so **https://example.net/** is working well but the **https:** is not showing as default in my browser addressbar.

So How can I make my default domain address like this **https://example.net/** , instead of **example.net** ?

Comment: Have you added rewrite rule for `https` in your `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: No I did not added rewrite rule for https in my .htaccess file. How can I rewrite rule for https in .htaccess ? Can you please give me an exmaple of rewrite rule for https ?

Comment: First try changing your website/site address  from backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell your hosting to set it up for you, and you by your own sign up in google webmaster tools, set your default domain to HTTPS instead the HTTP.  That worked for me.

Also in all your internal or external links   use HTTPS in the HREF or use just //  instead Https://